# IronPython & Windows.Forms' Control type

Tags: .net, winforms, ironpython

I cannot get this working...

```
for CBControl in self._tabPage2.Controls:               
    if CBControl.GetType == System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox().GetType:
    ....
```

It is not working...

I need to identify the controls in the tab by tehir type and do something only on chcekboxes...

Help!

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing the GetType methods - you need parens after both GetTypes to call the methods:

```
if CBControl.GetType() == System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox().GetType():
```